# Find all corresponding values

Tags: r, vectorization

I like to give all values which are in the `dat` vector a corresponding value which I define in another vector (`new_value`). I already managed to do somehow, but I like to have a solution without loop:

```
dat <- c("a","c","b","a","a","c","a","b","b","a")  
old_value <- names(table(dat))
new_value <- 1:length(old_value)
new_dat <- rep(NA, length(dat))

for(z in 1:length(old_value)){
  new_dat[dat==old_value[z]] <- c(1:length(new_value))[z]
}
new_dat
```

I don't want to use additional libraries. Please only base solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `match`

```
new_dat <- new_value[match(dat, old_value)]
```

For the current example, even

```
match(dat, old_value)
```

should work

Comment: @and thanks, For that reason I used the first option